# How to create a dropdown list for user input in sql, using sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Can we achieve this in SQL, using SQL Developer? instead of entering user input, can I pic the user input from the list.

```
SELECT * FROM HR.LOCATIONS
WHERE country_id LIKE '&COUNTRY_ID%';
```

Please review the image enclosed.

[SQL User Input expected as dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5nct.png)

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  It sounds like you're trying to build a GUI for users in which case SQL Developer isn't really the right tool.  It would be trivial to build a small APEX application that would do this.  In SQL Developer, you could just do a `select *` with no predicate and then filter the query results which would give you the list of values you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Actually, the above mention question is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

I have multiple instances like Prod, QA, Test in a total of 18, instances and users are assigned to these instances.
To fetch a user's details I need to type the instance name as an input to get their details.

I thought, if I could put these Instances names in a dropdown list then it will be easy to run the query. 
Or any other way I could achieve it. 

This is completely a SQL task using the SQL developer I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It still sounds like you are describing either a trivial application or something where it would make more sense to do a `select *` and then let the client filter the results.  I suppose maybe you want to build a drill-down report in SQL Developer, i.e. http://when-others-then-null.blogspot.com/2017/10/sql-developer-drill-down-reports.html

Comment: You tagged [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer) which has a way to prompt using dropdown lists and checkboxes etc. Are you using PL/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can satisfy this requirement using reports with child reports. To illustrate with the emp/dept schema.

1. Create a report called "DEPT" with SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM dept
```

2. Add a child report to this report named EMP with SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE depno = :deptno
```

When you run the dept report and click on a row, the corresponding rows in the emp table will be displayed in the child report. You can map this to your tables: the master report would be your instance report and the user details the child report.